# JBPM 4.4 resource adapter

Tags: jbpm, jca

Is there any JCA Resource adapter available for JBPM which can be used? How is JBPM used in production environment where we dont have Jboss App server?

Answer (score 0):

See http://code.google.com/p/drools-jca/.

Comment: You didn't answer the second part of the question, please try to provide a more elaborate answer rather than just a link.